# How to find an "x" amount of closest elements to a centroid

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am working on a dataset that is very high dimensional and have performed k-means clustering on it. I am trying to find the 20 closest points to each centroid. The dimensions of the dataset (X_emb) is 10 x 2816. Provided is code that I used to find the single-most closest point to each centroid. The commented out code is a potential solution that I found, but I was not able to make it accurately work.

```
import numpy as np
import pickle as pkl
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances_argmin_min
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from visualization.make_video_v2 import make_video_from_numpy
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

n_s_train = 10000
df = pkl.load(open('cluster_data/mixed_finetuning_data.pkl', 'rb'))

N = len(df)
X = []
X_emb = []
for i in range(N):
    play = df.iloc[i]
    if df.iloc[i].label == 1:
        X_emb.append(play['embedding'])
        X.append(play['input'])


X_emb = np.array(X_emb)
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=10)
kmeans.fit(X_emb)

results = kmeans.cluster_centers_

closest, _ = pairwise_distances_argmin_min(kmeans.cluster_centers_, X)


# def find_k_closest(centroids, data, k=1, distance_norm=2):
#     kdtree = cKDTree(data, leafsize=30)
#     distances, indices = kdtree.query(centroids, k, p=distance_norm)
#     if k > 1:
#         indices = indices[:,-1]
#     values = data[indices]
#     return indices, values
# indices, values = find_k_closest(results, X_emb)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pairwise distances to calculate the distances for every point with the centroids with every point in X_emb, then using numpy finding the index of the min 20 elements and finally geting them from X_emb

```
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances

distances = pairwise_distances(centroids, X_emb, metric='euclidean')
ind = [np.argpartition(i, 20)[:20] for i in distances]
closest = [X_emb[indexes] for indexes in ind]
```

The shape of closest will be (num of centroids x 20)

Answer (score -1):

You can the `NearestNeighbors` class from sklearn this way:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

def find_k_closest(centroids, data):
    nns = {}
    neighbors = NearesNieghbors(n_neighbors=20).fit(data)
    for center in centroids:
        nns[center] = neighbors.kneighbors(center, return_distance=false)
    return nns
```

the nns dictionary should contain the centers as key and the list of neighbors as value